# Including a C# library in a static way

Tags: windows-store-apps, static-libraries

Is there a way to use a C# library in Windows Store app, so that is doesn't produce a separate DLL, but its modules are included in main assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ILMerge by Microsoft - [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will mark it as solution. But there is a concern: if I merge two assemblies, will it be as efficient  (in time and app size) as having all in a single project, or the library modules will still be called as external ones? Also, the obfuscation will probably keep external names.